# Extract Month and Year only from DateTimePickerModal react native

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I want to extract Month and year from the picker DateTimePickerModal for credit card expiry selection for my application. The user will click on the dropdown icon and on click it will pop up the calendar. On selection of date, it will set it to the input text. Currently it is coming in this format (2020-11-13T12:52:09.002Z).

Below is my code

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import { DrawerActions } from "@react-navigation/native";
import CustomHeaderBar from "../components/CustomHeaderBarComponent";
import ButtonComponent from "../components/ButtonComponent";
import DateTimePickerModal from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";
import { Entypo } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const PaymentScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [isDatePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisibility] = useState(false);
  const [dateText, setDateText] = useState("");

  const showDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(true);
  };

  const hideDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(false);
  };

  const handleConfirm = (date) => {
    setDateText(JSON.stringify(date));
    console.warn(date);
    hideDatePicker();
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CustomHeaderBar
        label="Payment"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());
        }}
      />
      <View style={styles.RatingView}>
        <View style={styles.WrapperView}>
          <Text style={styles.PaymentText}>$ 250.00</Text>
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.lowerHalfStyle}>
        <Text style={styles.TextStyle}>Payment Method</Text>
        <View style={styles.MarginFromTop}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.TextInputStyle}
            placeholder="Card No"
          ></TextInput>

          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.TextInputStyle}
              placeholder="Expiry Date (MM/YY)"
              value={dateText}
            ></TextInput>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={showDatePicker}>
              <Entypo name="chevron-down" size={24} color="#000000" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <DateTimePickerModal
              isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
              mode="date"
              onConfirm={handleConfirm}
              onCancel={hideDatePicker}
            />
          </View>

          <TextInput
            style={styles.TextInputStyle}
            placeholder="CVC"
          ></TextInput>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.MarginFromTop}>
          <ButtonComponent label="PAY" />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
export default PaymentScreen;
```

Please guide how to achieve this functionality, want to display it in format MM/YY as per screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
…
import moment from "moment"; // add this

const PaymentScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

  …..

  const handleConfirm = (date) => {
    //setDateText(JSON.stringify(date)); // remove this
    console.warn(date);
    const monthAndYear = moment(date).format("MM/YYYY”); // add this
    setDateText(monthAndYear);
    hideDatePicker();
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      ……
    </View>
  );
};
export default PaymentScreen;
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine with moment library. Thanks a lot

Comment: What if I want to display only month and year in calendar and date doesn't even pop up for selection?

Comment: @Nizami Date actually binds with Month and year. I think for that, you would have to customize it.